# Windows 7 wired networking problems

Tags: windows-7, networking

I have a desktop playing the role of a server, which is always on and runs Windows 7 Ultimate.  Internet connection sharing runs here to give internet access to all the computers in the house. It has a Gbit net port.
There is a gigabit unmanaged switch connecting a desktop PC with Windows 7 Ultimate (Gbit net port), a laptop with Windows 7 Ultimate connected via a wireless (N) access point.
Finally connected with the switch is a media player (neoTV 550) with a 100 Mbps net port.

All was fine with XP on the server.  Since the Windows 7 Upgrade I got better bandwidth in file transfers touching 90 KBs. But I have 2 problems

1. Windows Explorer: clicking on a shared drive, there might be a waiting time of a few seconds. After that all is very fast for many hours or days until it happens again.  This happens once in a while. It could be once per day or once per week with no apparent pattern.
2. The neoTV 550 does not connect with the shared drives anymore.  It connects correctly with the network. It gets the IP address and all. It connects to the internet but not to the shared drives.  Then after a few minutes or hours, sometimes days, the connection comes back and all works perfectly. Even if all other computers can connect to the shared drives without any problem.

Cables are all quality CAT7.

What I have already tried:

- flushdns
- delete ARP cache
- autotuning disabled
- Removed RDC (Remote Differential Compression)
- Removed IPv6
- Autonegotiation set to 1000 Mbps full duplex (not automatic).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, waiting a couple seconds for a network drive to open is considered GOOD PERFORMANCE. Not only is the server serving other connections but authentication must take place which takes a little bit. Normal.

However, mapped drives (They are mapped yes?) dropping in and out of the atmosphere is not normal. Name resolution on a network with no central DNS server is shoddy at best. If your network is small enough, consider statically mapping IP addresses to host names in your HOST file or assign static IP addresses and map the drives to the address rather than the host name.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  It is more 10 secs than a couple, however the strange thing is that it happens just once in a while. I agree with you though that it is not a big problem.  regarding the second: the DNS should be the server, all IP config points to it as DNS.  The shares are shared from the server and mapped to drives on the clients. All clients maps the shares with the server name and it works fine.  The only problem is with the NEO that maps them with the TCP/IP address. Very weird!